# Variable expression not able to fetch model object data from controller

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, thymeleaf

I use variable expression to use model controller data in Thymeleaf but it throw this error:

```
Cannot resolve 'product' 
 Inspection info:
Reports unresolved references and invalid Thymeleaf expressions.
Example:
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
  <form th:object="${unknownPet}"  <!-- Cannot resolve 'unknownPet'  -->
        class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="*{id}" /> <!-- Cannot resolve 'id'  -->
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head th:replace="/fragments/head"></head>

<body>

<nav th:replace="/fragments/nav :: nav-admin"></nav>

<div class="container">

    <h1 class="display-2">Products</h1>
    <a href="/admin/products/add" class="btn btn-primary mb-5">Add new</a>

    <div th:if="${message}" th:text="${message}" th:class="${'alert ' + alertClass}"></div>

    <div th:if="${!products.empty}">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="product: ${products}">
                <td th:text="${product.name}"></td>
                <td>
                    <img style="width: 100px;" th:src="@{'/media/' + ${product.image}}">
                </td>
                <td th:text="${cats[__${product.categoryId}__]}"></td>
                <td th:text="'$ ' + ${product.price}"></td>
                <td><a th:href="@{'/admin/products/edit/' + ${product.id}}">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a th:href="@{'/admin/products/delete/' + ${product.id}}" class="confirmDeletion">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <nav class="mt-3" th:if="${count > perPage}">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="page-item" th:if="${page > 0}">
                <a th:href="@{${#httpServletRequest.requestURI}} + '?page=__${page-1}__'" class="page-link">Previous</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item" th:each="number: ${#numbers.sequence(0, pageCount-1)}" th:classappend="${page==number} ? 'active' : ''">
                <a th:href="@{${#httpServletRequest.requestURI}} + '?page=__${number}__'" class="page-link" th:text="${number+1}"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item" th:if="${page < pageCount-1}">
                <a th:href="@{${#httpServletRequest.requestURI}} + '?page=__${page+1}__'" class="page-link">Next</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div th:unless="${!products.empty}">
        <h4 class="display-4">There are no products at the moment</h4>
    </div>

</div>

<div th:replace="/fragments/footer"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

adminproductController.kt:

```
package com.example.cms.controller

import com.example.cms.entity.Category
import com.example.cms.entity.Product
import com.example.cms.repository.CategoryRepository
import com.example.cms.repository.ProductRepository
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
import org.springframework.ui.Model
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes
import java.io.IOException
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths
import javax.validation.Valid
import kotlin.math.ceil

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/products")
class AdminProductController {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var productRepository: ProductRepository
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var categoryRepository: CategoryRepository

    @GetMapping
    fun index(model: Model, @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) p: Int?): String? {
        val perPage = 6
        val page = p ?: 0
        val pageable: Pageable = PageRequest.of(page, perPage)
        val product: Page<Product> = productRepository.finAll(pageable)
        val categories: List<Category> = categoryRepository.findAll()
        val cats = HashMap<Long?, String>()
        for (cat in categories) {
            cats[cat.id] = cat.name
        }
        model.addAttribute("product", product)
        model.addAttribute("cats", cats)
        val count: Long = productRepository.count()
        val pageCount = ceil(count.toDouble() / perPage.toDouble())
        model.addAttribute("pageCount", pageCount.toLong())
        model.addAttribute("perPage", perPage)
        model.addAttribute("count", count)
        model.addAttribute("page", page)
        return "/resources/admin/products/index.html"
    }
    @GetMapping("/add")
    fun add(product: Product?, model: Model): String? {
        val categories: List<Category> = categoryRepository.findAll()
        model.addAttribute("categories", categories)
        return "admin/products/add"
    }
    @PostMapping("/add")
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun add(
        @Valid
        product:Product,
        bindingResult: BindingResult,
        file: MultipartFile,
        redirectAttributes: RedirectAttributes,
        model: Model
    ): String? {
        val categories: List<Category> = categoryRepository.findAll()
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("categories", categories)
            return "admin/products/add"
        }
        var fileOK = false
        val bytes = file.bytes
        val filename = file.originalFilename
        val path = Paths.get("src/main/resources/static/media/$filename")
        if (filename!!.endsWith("jpg") || filename.endsWith("png")) {
            fileOK = true
        }
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Product added")
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("alertClass", "alert-success")
        val slug: String = product.name.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "-")
        val productExists: Product = productRepository.findBySlug(slug)
        if (!fileOK) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Image must be a jpg or a png")
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("alertClass", "alert-danger")
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("product", product)
        } else if (productExists != null) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Product exists, choose another")
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("alertClass", "alert-danger")
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("product", product)
        } else {
            product.slug=slug
            product.image=filename
            productRepository.save(product)
            Files.write(path, bytes)
        }
        return "redirect:/admin/products/add"
    }
    @GetMapping("/edit/{id}")
    fun edit(@PathVariable id: Long, model: Model): String? {
        val product: Product = productRepository.getOne(id)
        val categories: List<Category> = categoryRepository.findAll()
        model.addAttribute("product", product)
        model.addAttribute("categories", categories)
        return "admin/products/edit"
    }

    @PostMapping("/edit")
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun edit(
        @Valid
        product: Product,
        bindingResult: BindingResult,
        file: MultipartFile,
        redirectAttributes: RedirectAttributes,
        model: Model
    ): String? {
        val currentProduct: Product = product.id.let { productRepository.getOne(it) }
        val categories: List<Category> = categoryRepository.findAll()
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("productName", currentProduct.name)
            model.addAttribute("categories", categories)
            return "admin/products/edit"
        }
        var fileOK = false
        val bytes = file.bytes
        val filename = file.originalFilename
        val path = Paths.get("src/main/resources/static/media/$filename")
        if (!file.isEmpty) {
            if (filename!!.endsWith("jpg") || filename.endsWith("png")) {
                fileOK = true
            }
        } else {
            fileOK = true
        }
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Product edited")
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("alertClass", "alert-success")
        val slug: String = product.name.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "-")
        val productExists: Product? = product.id.let { productRepository.findBySlugAndIdNot(slug, it) }
        if (!fileOK) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Image must be a jpg or a png")
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("alertClass", "alert-danger")
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("product", product)
        } else if (productExists != null) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Product exists, choose another")
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("alertClass", "alert-danger")
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("product", product)
        } else {
            if (!file.isEmpty) {
                val path2 = Paths.get("src/main/resources/static/media/" + currentProduct.image)
                Files.delete(path2)
                if (filename != null) {
                    product.image=filename
                }
                Files.write(path, bytes)
            } else {
                product.image=currentProduct.image// setImage(currentProduct.Image())
            }
            productRepository.save(product)
        }
        return "redirect:/admin/products/edit/" + product.id
    }

    @GetMapping("/delete/{id}")
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun delete(@PathVariable id: Long, redirectAttributes: RedirectAttributes): String? {
        val product: Product = productRepository.getOne(id)
        val currentProduct: Product = product.id.let { productRepository.getOne(it) }
        val path2 = Paths.get("src/main/resources/static/media/" + currentProduct.image)
        Files.delete(path2)
        productRepository.deleteById(id)
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Product deleted")
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("alertClass", "alert-success")
        return "redirect:/admin/products"
    }

}
```

I define all the things properly but I don't know where I make a mistake. Every variable expression values shows above type of error.

I use Intellij 21.2 ultimate version.

Comment: Like it mentions in the error message, you need to include `xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"` in your page's `<html>` tag. Currently you only have this: `<html lang="en">`. See [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#a-multi-language-welcome) in the official documentation for more information about this.

Comment: if i added     <!doctype html "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-4.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"> get same type of error .There nothing changes in the error.I already try this trick

Comment: What you show in your comment is very different from the example in the error message (and also, templates should not need the `doctype` directive - you should be able to use HTML5). The change in your comment is also very different from the example in the official documentation I linked to. This change is not a trick, it is necessary - but, in your case, it may not be sufficient to solve your problem.

Comment: A correction to my earlier comment - and my apologies, it was incorrect. Adding the namespace is only a recommendation - it is certainly not necessary.